# Angular reports no filetype for csv on Windows

Tags: angular, typescript

I develop on Linux and had an upload tool that checks whether the uploaded file is indeed of the type 'text/csv'. `file.type` correctly reports this on Ubuntu Linux with Firefox. On Windows, however, the filetype is an empty string, regardless which browser I'm using.

Is this OS dependent, browser dependent, or how is the file type determined that it is so unreliable?

Comment: Which angular library you are using for file upload?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm not using any special libraries, just the HTML input element has an onchange event to a handler which receives an object that implements `FileList`